Does the Code interpreter in Azure open AI support Arabic language from the files
I'm trying to use the Azure OpenAI and the code interpreter to perform some data analysis on some CSV files but it doesn't return the Arabic values from the files.
Instead, it shows it as question marks (????).
If there some docs about it please provide me with the links.

Can you brief on what kind of data it is. @hamzah jazi

provide me the sample data you are using. and your expecting output

@JayashankarGS it's names and addresses and some information about the people records and I want to get some statistical info about the data and all the data is in Arabic

Are you trying in chat playground on your own data?

I have tried uploading a CSV file containing the Arabic language, and it worked fine, providing a table output.

The problem here is due to encoding.
You need to upload a UTF-8 encoded file, as shown in the screenshot below. Then, you will get the output correctly.

If the code interpreter returns a Pandas CSV load, then pandas does not recognize the file correctly if it is not encoded properly.
Therefore, make sure to give the prompt saying to use the correct encoding.

@hamzah jazi  Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
